# How to add Custom fields in civicrm contribution page?

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, civicrm-home

How to add Custom fields in civicrm contribution page - below the title text field of contribution page form

Comment: Please read the link I guess this should help - https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/

Answer (score 2):

1. Under Administer > Custom Data and Screens, Create your Custom Fields
2. Under Administer > Profiles, Create a Profile that has your Custom Fields in it.
3. Under Contributions > Manage Contribution Pages, select the Page you want it to appear on. Under the Include Profiles tab, add that Profile. You can add it at the a) "top" (with the donor profile) this is below the price sets/contribution amounts but above the billing info or b) "bottom" of the Contribution Page just before the Confirm button. Those are the only two location options for placing Custom Fields on a contribution page.

You cannot make it appear right under the title.

Comment: Well, you might be able to get the top one to go there, but that would require creating a custom template file and understanding how all the template files work and go together. They are quite easy to mess up.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need field associated with contribution page or contribution?

**For contribution**:

You can create custom group extending contribution and then add custom field in it and then include the custom field in a profile.

**For Contribution page:**

Currently CiviCRM doesn't allow to create custom field to extend contribution page. [JMA Consulting](http://jmaconsulting.biz/home) have developed an [extension](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.contributionpagecustomfield) to have custom field extend contribution page. This extension is not yet released in civicrm.org but they are hoping it to release it soon. You can try by downloading and installing manually.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create custom fields through Administer->Customize Data and Screens->Custom Fields
2. Then create a profile through Administer->Customize Data and Screens->Profiles and use created custom fields in profile
3. Use the created profile in contribution page where you want the custom fields, you can add the profile in contribution page settings in 'Profiles' tab.