# How to add a custom field to the civicontribute dashboard?

Tags: civicontribute, dashboard, column

I've researched a bit on how to create a custom field and believe I understand the process ([from this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22104/how-to-add-custom-fields-in-civicrm-contribution-page)), but I would now like to add the content of this field to the [CiviContribute dashboard](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22104/how-to-add-custom-fields-in-civicrm-contribution-page).

To explain, we need a title field on contribution pages that doesn't get exposed publicly. This would allow us to use the same title on multiple contribution pages which we could use in different campaigns, but be able to tell the difference between them with an "internal" title. At present, the Source columnbn on the dashboard uses the publicly exposed title, but we'd like to swap it out for the custom "internal" title or add that column to the dashboard alongside the Source column.

I was not able to find how to do this without coding, but continue to hope that the option exists under Administer somewhere.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tony - no can't be done via UI - requires a minor tweak to the tpl file that builds that page

Comment: Thanks, @petednz-fuzion. Sorry for the delay in acknowledging.